# How do I convert a partially transparent image into polygons?

Tags: physics, algorithm, image, gleed2d

I'm using *GLEE2D*, a level editor allowing me to import images, scale them, rotate them, and position them onto layers and export the data into XML format. However, it does not tell me objects' boundaries. I can calculate them, but only given the original image's polygons.

How do I get polygons of objects in a transparent image?

An example object (I outlined it):

[image: example object; an astronaut meerkat]

How would I turn the object, knowing the scaled size of the image, into polygons? Is there an algorithm for this? I'll use OpenGL to draw them.

Comment: If you just want a tool to do this, Physics Editor will do quite well. It had an auto trace feature that does exactly what you want. http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

Comment: What results do you expect, say from that example image? (You've outlined it, but I don't see any polygons.)

Comment: To turn the outlines shape into polygons (pref triangles), for use with a physics engine and OpenGL.

Comment: You can do this with marching squares. I believe NAPE 2 has a working implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Marching Squares algorithm](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/03/01/using-marching-squares-algorithm-to-trace-the-contour-of-an-image/) to generate the 2d-mesh you want.
After using the marching squares to outline the object, you could use [this library](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) to do the triangulation.